# how to re initiate a object when condition comes true in a member method?

Tags: c#

for example

```
         Class AClass
            {
               public AClass (int a)
               {...}
               public void DoIt()
               {
                 ...
                 c = PreDo();
                 ...
               }
               private int PreDo()
               { ...
                 if (b==1)
                     xxxxx
                 ...
               }
            }

         int Main ()
             {
               AClass myClass = new AClass(2);
               myClass.DoIt();  //*
             }
```

* Here I wanna once xxxx is called then myClass is no long useful.

Hence it would try out `myClass = new AClass(3), myClass.DoIt()` in the `main` instead, and so on.

Comment: Your methods and variables don't seem to relate to one another at all.

Comment: Please refactor you question so that it's readable. At present I'm finding it hard to determine the question.

Comment: exactly what are you aiming to achieve here? tell us why you're doing what and where you need help

Answer (score 0):

accross all instances or only in one instance? ... just use a (static) variable `notRunAllready` to remember the called (so `if (b==1)` goes to `if (!notRunAllready && b==1)`) and you set `notRunAllready` to `true` in xxxx

Answer (score 0):

May be I understood what you are talking about. 
You probably want to make conditional execution based on some class internal variable wich initialized in class's constructor.

1. Declare them like a `static` like @CKoening says. But it's wired by we, cause it's not absolutely clear what will gonna happen during the call.
2. The best solution to make conditional execution is add parameters to your `DoIt(..)` method, by making esplicit "what is gonna be happen if I pass this parameter to the function".

If this is not what you're asking about, please explain better.